# How Do I create a shortcode to dispaly a go to top button on any page or post

Tags: shortcode

I am creating a wordpress site, and on every page I would require go to top button. So I was thinking to get some shortcode to do this so that I  can insert anywhere.
Thanks

Comment: what have you done in order to accomplish that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi You can use this below code in your function.php

```
    add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('go-to-top', 'gtp_function');
}


function gtp_function($atts) {
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'text' => '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-3"></i>',
      'speed'=>500,
      'bottom'=>20,
      'right'=> 20
   ), $atts));
   ?>
  <script>
  $ = jQuery.noConflict();
      (function($){
                $.fn.addScrollToTopButton = function(options){
                    var $t = $(this);

                        var settings = $.extend({
                            text : "<a href='#' style='opacity:0.5; font-size:40px' onmouseleave=\"this.style.color='grey'\" onMouseOver=\"this.style.color='#0066CC'\"><i class='fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-6'></i></a>",
                            speed: 500,
                            bottom:20,
                            right: 20
                        },options);

                        return this.each(function(){
                            $t.html(settings.text);
                            $t.css({'position':'fixed', 'bottom':settings.bottom , 'right':settings.right});
                            $t.hide();
                            $(document).scroll(function(){
                                if($(document).scrollTop()==0)
                                {
                                    $t.fadeOut(200);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $t.fadeIn(200);
                                }
                            });

                            $(this).click(function(){
                                if($(document).scrollTop()!=0)
                                {

                                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},settings.speed);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                }
            }(jQuery));
          $(function(){
                $('body').append('<div id="gtp"></div>');

                $('#gtp').addScrollToTopButton({speed:"<?php echo $speed ?>"});
            });
  </script>
  <?php

}
```

Comment: Instead of talking with yourself, read and follow http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts. It is OK to answer your own questions. It is **not allowed** to use multiple accounts to gain reputation.

Comment: Really do you think that you are right. can you prove thats my own account.

Comment: Keep in mind that moderators see a lot more information than regular users. Once you've merged your accounts, I will remove these comments.

Comment: sumit asked only 2 question and immediately you answer this what a great coincidence right !! Ah @dev don't try to prove yourself that you are smarter then experienced moderators.